# An "if mouseover" or a "do while mouseover" in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mouseevent

Is there a JavaScript or jQuery solution to run a function repeatedly (after `setTimeout`) while the mouse is over a DOM object?  Otherwise said, is there a JavaScript "do while mouseover" (or "if mouseover")?

```
    $('someObject').bind('mouseover', function() {

        //Do the following while mouseover 
        $('someOtherObject').css('margin-left',adjustedLeft + 'px');
        setTimeout(/*do it again*/,25);

    });
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
$('someObject').on('mouseenter', function() {
    this.iid = setInterval(function() {
       // do something           
    }, 25);
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
});
```

[Example Look here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/YjC6y/29/)

Comment: i use new bind style of jQuery

Comment: Is it possible to execute that event once per hover? Currently it will be executed multiple times until the element is hovered. I want to do that just once.

Comment: What is the point of having `this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid)` wouldn't `clearInterval` suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this issue using the onmouseout event.
Start whatever you intended to do while the mouse is over the specified component on the mouseover event.
When onmouseout event occurs i would stop it.

Answer (score 0):

i use new bind style of jQuery.

```
$(el).bind({
'mouseenter': function(){console.log('Mouse over');}, 
'mouseleave': function(){console.log('Mouse leave');}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old, but I think the proper function is already in JavaScript, [onmousemove](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp) does just that.

Answer (score 0):

```
OBJ.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  focus=true;
});
OBJ.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  focus=false;
});
```

Just in case you don't want to use jquery you can use this :)