# Javascript "while hovered" loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Can anybody help me on this one...I have a button which when is hovered, triggers an action. But I'd like it to repeat it for as long as the button is hovered.

I'd appreciate any solution, be it in jquery or pure javascript - here is how my code looks at this moment (in jquery):

```
var scrollingposition = 0;

$('#button').hover(function(){
++scrollingposition;
    $('#object').css("right", scrollingposition);
    });
```

Now how can i put this into some kind of while loop, so that #object is moving px by px for as #button is hovered, not just when the mouse enters it?

Comment: Archive purpose: Selected answer here was what I needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966273/an-if-mouseover-or-a-do-while-mouseover-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK... another stab at the answer:

```
$('myselector').each(function () {
  var hovered = false;
  var loop = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (hovered) {
      // ...
    }
  }, 250);

  $(this).hover(
    function () {
      hovered = true;
    },
    function () {
      hovered = false;
    }
  );
});
```

The `250` means the task repeats every quarter of a second. You can decrease this number to make it faster or increase it to make it slower.

Comment: Glad it works for you. I'm not 100% happy with this solution because I'm sure there must be a cleaner one... this solution has the loop running all the time (even when not hovered), and it sets up a new loop for each element in the selector. So if anyone's got something better, please do suggest it.

Comment: @NathanMacInnes: your code is a good start, so I upvoted it. But I posted a correction not to call the function repeatedly (which is not necessary when not hovering the element): http://stackoverflow.com/a/14284748/517705.

Answer (score 4):

[Nathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265485/javascript-while-hovered-loop/4266324#4266324) is a good start, but **you should also use [window.clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval)** when the mouse leaves the element ([mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event) to cancel the repeated action which was set up using [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval), because this way the "loop" is running only when the mouse pointer enters the element ([mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event).

Here is a sample code:

```js
  function doSomethingRepeatedly(){
    // do this repeatedly when hovering the element
  }

  var intervalId;

  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myelement').hover(function () {
      var intervalDelay = 10;
      // call doSomethingRepeatedly() function repeatedly with 10ms delay between the function calls
      intervalId = setInterval(doSomethingRepeatedly, intervalDelay);
    }, function () {
      // cancel calling doSomethingRepeatedly() function repeatedly
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    });

  });
```

I created a sample code on jsFiddle which demonstrates how to scroll the background-image of an element left-to-right and then backwards on `hover` with the code shown above:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/HLT3J/15/

Answer (score 2):

If its an animation you can "stop" an animation half way through. So it looks like you're moving something to the left so you could do:

```
var maxScroll = 9999;
$('#button').hover(
    function(){ $('#object').animate({ "right":maxScroll+"px" }, 10000); },
    function(){ $('#object').stop(); } );
```

Comment: This isn't a good approach because your speed is going to be all over the place.  For example if we hover for a bit to start, our speed is 9999/10000 (approx 1px/ms), if we come out and hover again, say we scrolled half way the first time, now we're at 4999/1000, or .5px/ms...your duration would need to be calculated from the distance left to travel, otherwise it'll be proportional to it, and always changing.

Comment: Hi, thanks everyone for useful answers, I still need just a bit to make it really work: Nathan, while your solution makes perfect sense to me, it for some reason doesn't work, but blocks ("script on this page is too busy or is not responding - Thomas, your solution works, except there is the speed issue as Nick noted, but for me it manifests differently, the object constantly speeds up while hovered, and when i hover out and back in, it starts again slower and speeding up....does anyone guys knows how to push any of these solutions to work?  And thanks very much to everyone for the time put in

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttonHovered = false;
$('#button').hover(function () {
  buttonHovered = true;
  while (buttonHovered) {
    ...
  }
},
function () {
  buttonHovered = false;
});
```

If you want to do this for multiple objects, it might be better to make it a bit more object oriented than a global variable though.

**Edit:**
Think the best way of dealing with multiple objects is to put it in an .each() block:

```
$('myselector').each(function () {
  var hovered = false;
  $(this).hover(function () {
    hovered = true;
    while (hovered) {
      ...
    }
  },
  function () {
    hovered = false;
  });
});
```

**Edit2**:
Or you could do it by adding a class:

```
$('selector').hover(function () {
  $(this).addClass('hovered');
  while ($(this).hasClass('hovered')) {
    ...
  }
}, function () {
  $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, yes I need it on multiple objects, if there's a way you can share with me I'd highly appreciate it - I come from php, javascript noob...thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var scrollingposition = 0;

$('#button').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $obj = $("#object");
    while ( $this.is(":hover") ) {
        scrollingposition += 1;
        $obj.css("right", scrollingposition);
    }
});
```