# jquery Switch images on hover

Tags: jquery, image, slider, switch-statement, show

I got many divs with class 'Thumbnails' which contains 5 images like this

```
<div class='thumbnails'>

    <img src='image1.jpg' />
    <img src='image2.jpg' />
    <img src='image3.jpg' />
    <img src='image4.jpg' />
    <img src='image5.jpg' />

</div>
```

css:

```
.thumbnails{ position:relative; }
.thumbnails img{ position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; }
```

Every image have position:absolute; so by default image1 is on top

What i want to do is

When visitor hovers on 'thumbnails' div, it shows/switches every image 'Something like Slider' and on mouse out it returns to the default image(image1), and so on for each 'Thumbnails' div

All help will be appreciated

Comment: Yusuf said: i do not have images names, it will be results fetched from the database each product have its own images

Comment: That looks like a hash with image lists to me.  Each product has a list of images.  Link the view with that data structure and just display based on the key, which in this case is the product id or something unique.  I can't help you with syntax as I do not know what you are using.

Comment: Different way with JQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265485/javascript-while-hovered-loop/4266324#4266324

Comment: the question is simple, i got a div and inside of it 5 images, but only 1 is displayed because the images have position:absolute; what i want is when user hover on the top image or on thumbnails div it shows other images slightly and when user take his mouse off it returns to the default image

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to bind a .mouseenter() event on #thumbnails that calls a function that uses .animate(). That function then can run an animation, then on complete ('#image'+counter), and run the function again. (you can also create a setInterval for this to work instead of on complete) Just make it so that you set a varible that detects .mouseleave() to stop the animation chain started by .mouseenter()

Docs:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

http://api.jquery.com/animate/