# Javascript / css: Using buttons to vertically scroll page

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I actually have a div with a staticheight and 100% width. Currently this div has `overflow:auto` so there is a vertical scrollbar.

But for this project it's necessary to have this div without any scrollbars. So I have two buttons - one at the div's top and one at the end for scrolling. But until now I was unable to find a solution to make the div scrolling (for several px OR scrolling while mouseover) using this buttons.

(I'm commonly using jQuery, but weren't able to use it's `scrollTop()`-Method)

So please help me!

Comment: Why not just use the Page Up and Page Down keys and hide the scrollbar?

Comment: @Tom for me thats not a kind of intuitive usage :p

Comment: Why weren't you able to use `scrollTop()`? (Hint: post the code you tried).

Comment: @MxAgent: Why hide the scroll bar then? Your idea is inconsistent with standards...

Comment: @Tom Here is a similar scrolling-solution: http://www.michaelheinsen.de/ (click on imprint) - But this is implemented in flash - I need this kind of scrollsolution for css / js

Comment: @MxAgent: What a slow site... And that is such a bad solution, I can't scroll with my mouse! Why do I need to aim if I want to scroll? All you are going to do with wasting time on implementing this is annoying your users...

Comment: customer-sastisfaction.. Couldn't persuade him for having simple scrollbars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd expect `scrollTop` to be just what you were looking for (though I would argue against this user experience barring a ***really*** good reason to be this non-standard).

It works for me ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/upofob)):

CSS:

```
#theDiv {
  height: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="btnDown" type="button" value="Down">
<input id="btnUp"   type="button" value="Up">
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

JavaScript w/jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var theDiv;

  theDiv = $("#theDiv");
  fill();

  $("#btnDown").click(function() {
    theDiv.scrollTop(theDiv.scrollTop() + 10);
  });
  $("#btnUp").click(function() {
    var top = Math.max(theDiv.scrollTop() - 10, 0);
    theDiv.scrollTop(top);
  });

  function fill() {
    var n, s;

    s = "Line 0";
    for (n = 1; n < 20; ++n) {
      s += "<br>Line " + n;
    }
    theDiv.html(s);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That's working perfectly for me together with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966273/an-if-mouseover-or-a-do-while-mouseover-in-javascript-jquery/3966307#3966307 :)