# Do while mouseover , do other thing while mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, mouseover, mouseout

I saw this code in another question , I thought I might make it work for an image too, but since I am a newbie in jquery, I didn't do much.

Here is the code:

```
$('someObject').bind('mouseover', function() {

    //Do the following while mouseover 
    $('someOtherObject').css('margin-left',adjustedLeft + 'px');
    setTimeout(/*do it again*/,25);

});
```

I saw it in this question right here:
[An "if mouseover" or a "do while mouseover" in JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966273/an-if-mouseover-or-a-do-while-mouseover-in-javascript-jquery?answertab=active#tab-top)

There is an example below it also, but that one works for text fields.

I want mine to work for images,  basically i have 2 images one over another and i want to make a fading effect, so something like

while mouseover , every 0,01sec , lower the opacity by 0.01 ,till 0,01
the moment the mouse leaves the image(button) , stop lowering the opacity and start heightening it again by 0.01 every 0.01sec till 0.99 opacity

Just to be clear again , i got 2 images(buttons) 1 above the other , i want to lower and then heighten the opacity of the upper button. 
Also i saw another type of fade , but the 2 buttons were on 1 image , but for me(the newbie) its too advanced i guess, but i might look at that , its a nice way to use less images i guess.

Just in case , here is the link to the example too : http://jsfiddle.net/YjC6y/29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('someObject').mouseover(function() {
   $('someOtherObject').animate({
         opacity: 0
    })
}).mouseout(function() {
   $('someOtherObject').animate({
         opacity: 0.99
    })
});
```

Comment: Is this preferable to $().hover with two functions?

Comment: Thank you , this really worked :)  , just instead of "someOtherObject" i used the same , if its another object, it doesn't animate properly
This is the code i used:

$(LowerImage).mouseover(function() {
   $(LowerImage).animate({
         opacity: 0
    })
}).mouseout(function() {
   $(LowerImage).animate({
         opacity: 0.99
    })
});

And one more thing , can i set the speed of the animation somewhere ? Don't get me wrong , the speed is good , i just want to know in case i need it somewhere else to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery hover http://api.jquery.com/hover/someObject

```
  $('someObject').hover(
        function () {
            // Set the effect you want when mouse is over the element
        },
        function () {
            // Set the effect for mouse leave
        }

    );
```

Hope this help :)