# Raphael JS - Start/Continue animating during mouseover. Pause animation on mouseout

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael, mouseover, mouseout

Using Raphael JS, is there a way to make a circle move to the right (or any direction) during mouseover, and then pause/stop the movement when the cursor is no longer on the circle.

I've tried few different methods, but they have bugs. One of the main issues is: if the mouse cursor doesn't move after entering the circle, "mouseout" will not be triggered once the circle moves to a location where the mouse cursor is no longer over top of the circle.

You'll see what I mean in these different attempts:

1) Animate with pause / resume:

jsfiddle.net/fKKNt/

- But the animation is jerky and unreliable. If you hover over the object, as the object moves outside of where the mouse cursor is, it doesn't trigger the "mouseout" listener.

2) Repositioning with mouseover & .attr("cx"):

jsfiddle.net/c4BFt/

- But we want the animation to continue while the cursor is in the circle too.

3) Using setInterval (as suggested in:
[An "if mouseover" or a "do while mouseover" in JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966273/an-if-mouseover-or-a-do-while-mouseover-in-javascript-jquery)):

jsfiddle.net/9bBcm/

- But "mouseout" is not called as the circle moves outside of where the cursor lies. I.e. the circle move to a location where "mouseout" should be called, but it is not called.
  The same thing happens with "hover":

jsfiddle.net/STruB/

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a much more elegant way to do this, but off the top of my head, you could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/D6Ps4/2/

In case that disappears for some reason, I've included the code below. The solution simply initiates the animation, then checks to see if the mouse cursor (note the e.offsetX/e.offsetY) is within the bounding box of your Raphael Object ([Element.getBBox()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getBBox)) at some set interval. If it is, do nothing and use setTimeout to check again in some time, if it's not, pause the animation.

```
    var paper = Raphael("holder");
    var animObject = Raphael.animation({cx: 400}, 5000);
    circle = paper.circle(90, 90, 45).attr({fill: "#0E4"});
    var timer;

    circle.mouseover(function(e) {
        var anim = function(shouldAnim) {
            if (shouldAnim) {
                circle.animate(animObject);
            }
            if (!mouseInsideCircle(e, circle)) {
                circle.pause();
                return;            
            } else {
                timer = setTimeout(function() {anim(false)}, 20);
            }
        }
        anim(true);
    });

    circle.mouseout(function() {
        this.pause();
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    var mouseInsideCircle = function(e, c) {
        var bb = c.getBBox();
        if (e.offsetX > bb.x && e.offsetY > bb.y) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm sure the solution is flawed (it's checking the boundBox, not the circle itself; it also assumes the circle is moving right) and perhaps not ideal, but it seems to work reasonably smoothly and hopefully gets you on the right path.