# Regular observable emission while DOM hovering

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, angular2-observables

Problem: looking for a way to get a regular event emission (saying every 200ms) while the user hovering a DOM element with RxJs on angular 5.

Actually, using `mouseover` via simple JS, angular or RxJs doesn't produce a regular event and the behavior differs from browsers. Using `debounce` doesn't help about event emission.

So, I thought instead using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and a timer between them. But I have no idea how to start and stop a timer from events.

Something like [this solution in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3966307/7457567), but with observables.

A (bad) code is better than 1000 words:

```js
// RxJs syntax in typescript for angular
const enter = fromEvent(nativeElement, "mouseenter");
const leave = fromEvent(nativeElement, "mouseleave");

// Bad code, just an idea
enter.pipe(
  merge(interval(200 /* ms */)),
  takeUntil(leave)
).subscribe(event => console.log("hovering", event));
```

Do you know if it is possible to start an interval emission after each `mouseenter`?

For libraries, I'm using **RxJs 5** with Angular 5 on typescript 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were very close. Just instead of `merge` you should use `mergeMap` that will subscribe to the `interval` Observable only after an emission from `enter`. Then you probably want to use `repeat()` as well that will repeat the process after every `leave` emission (however, this depends on how use/call this code).

```
enter.pipe(
  mergeMap(() => interval(200 /* ms */)),
  takeUntil(leave),
  repeat(),
).subscribe(event => console.log("hovering", event));
```

See demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-nrb7km?file=index.ts

Comment: That it! Thanks a million.
Is the `repeat()` method could produce any memory leak?

Comment: @Bérenger-appvizer- That's very unlikely. But if you use this in a component you should keep the subscription `const sub = enter.pipe(...).subscribe()` and unsubscribe when destroying the component `sub.unsubscribe()`